# How to preserve layout through different views of same controller in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, view

I'm using cakephp and I have set a simple site, when rendering index() it works fine
but when programming other methods of the same controller, the views for them do not show the 
background, it's like it cannot find the images, I thought the layout would be preserved for all views.

Comment: Could you post code? The action and view of a view that's not showing the background for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Your `View/Layouts/default.ctp` layout file will always be used unless specified otherwise.  If it's not showing a background, it's like you're using an incorrect path for the image, css...etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a layout to all methods of a particular controller (but not all other controllers) then use a **theme**.

Controller Code:

```
class MyThingController extends AppController {
   public $theme = 'MyTheme';
       ....
}
```

Next you have to put your layout file in:
`/app/View/Themed/MyTheme/Layouts/default.ctp`

Then all methods in your controller will use this layout by default.

See here for more info: [enter link description here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html)

(note: this answer applies to Cake version 2.1+)